# How to apply style to immedate tag and not after text

Tags: html, css

I am bit concerned, how can I add style to only immediate child and not after the some plain text.

Ex.

I have structure like:
1)

```
<div>
plain text lorm ipusm
<ul><li>test content</li></ul>
<ul><li>test content</li></ul>
</div>
```

If I add rule for ul should not apply. If I set background then it should not be applied here as it has some text before ul "plain txt lorm ipsum"

and 2)

```
<div>
<ul><li>test content</li></ul>
<ul><li>test content</li></ul>
</div>
```

If I add rule for ul should apply to this ul as there is not text before it.

I dont have any css selector, wants to apply style to ul immediate to div as in 2nd example not as in 1st. I mean in first ex. inside div there are some text and then ul. In that case style should not be applied and in 2nd ul is immediate to div, style should applied to only first ul.

I have tried `div > ul:first-child` but it applicable in both the cases

**In short, style should not apply to the ul if there is any text in between div and ul**

Comment: In other words you only want to apply the CSS if the `<ul>` is the first child of the `<div>` and not if there's any text between the two?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: You can use `first-of-type` for it. check answer

Comment: No jquery @Ihazkode, pure css only.

Comment: @j08691 Yes, you are right

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like assuming you are going to have ul as only n^th (2) child

```css
div:nth-child(2) >ul:first-child{
  color : red;
}
```

```html
<div>
plain text lorm ipusm
<ul><li>test content</li></ul>
<ul><li>test content</li></ul>
</div>
========================================
<div>
<ul><li>test content</li></ul>
<ul><li>test content</li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not correct. 
I have given two scenarios. Your code is working only for the first div and also the wrong one. Style should not apply to first. Should applied in second scenario where there is no preceding text to ul.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the div has an immediate text then decide to add the style or not, like :

```
$("div").each(function(){
  if( $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text().trim() !== ""){
    console.log('Do not add style');
  }else{
    console.log('Add style');
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

**Pure JS solution :**

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  var element = divs[i], text = '';

  for (var j = 0; j < element.childNodes.length; ++j)
    if (element.childNodes[i].nodeType === 3)
      text += element.childNodes[j].textContent;

  if (text.trim() === "") {
    element.querySelector('ul').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  plain text lorm ipusm
  <ul>
    <li>test content</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>test content</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li>test content</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>test content</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery Solution :**

```js
$("div").each(function(){
  if( $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text().trim() === ""){
    $('ul:first-of-type',this).css('background-color','green');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  plain text lorm ipusm
  <ul><li>test content</li></ul>
  <ul><li>test content</li></ul>
</div>

<div>
  <ul><li>test content</li></ul>
  <ul><li>test content</li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see a JavaScript tag, let alone jQuery, on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `first-of-type`. it works with the parent so effect only immediate comes tag.

```css
div>ul:first-of-type {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>test content</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>test content</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div>
  plain text lorm ipusm
  <ul>
    <li>test content</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>test content</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: _I mean in first ex. inside div there are some text and then ul. In that case style should not be applied_

Comment: It should apply style to first ul and not in the case of second

Comment: @mukund is it your requirement right ? so downvoter pls explain why you do that.

Comment: Actually, I wants answer  like the first one. 
In your case it applies to all the ul, which is wrong.
And reverse of it. Means, should only apply style to ul, not starting with text.

Comment: I have given two different scenarios, both are different case. 1st scenario and 2 scenario - without preceding text as shown in question. Style should apply to second scenario ul only. and in same style should have no effect for 1st scenario